# Which neurodevelopmental disorders constitute learning disabilities?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, social-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, learning

I am actually looking at DSM-5 but I cannot find any exhaustive or otherwise comprehensive list or explicit association of which neurodevelopmental disorders are also learning disabilities.